# Returning a sequential number instead of timestamps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has two columns:

```
EventTimestamp
EventDescription
```

Instead of returning a bunch of timestamps from the first column, I'd like to return an integer indicating the sequence in which the "EventDescription" occurred, from earliest timestamp being "1" and incrementing with each row.

So the results would look something like:

```
1  Admission
2  Stuff happened
3  Discharged
```

How is this possible?

***EDIT***
I realized I left out an important detail. There's a 3rd significant column:

```
PatientID
EventTimestamp
EventDescription
```

So the RowNumber needs to start again with 1 for each PatientID. In other words, each PatientID needs its own series of RowNumbers. Accordingly, the results would look something like:

```
PT1  1  Admission
PT1  2  Stuff happened
PT1  3  Discharged
PT2  1  Admission
PT2  2  Stuff happened
PT2  3  Discharged
PT3  1  Admission
PT3  2  Stuff happened
PT3  3  Discharged
```

Comment: Will you have the same events happening for multiple objects/entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY EventTimestamp ASC) RowNo, 
       EventDescription,
       PatientId
FROM [TABLE]...
```

[ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

> Numbers the output of a result set. More specifically, returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Comment: Your answer is great, but I just realized I omitted a key piece of info. I added it under "EDIT" in the original post. Is this still possible?

Comment: Sure @Eliezer just change it to `OVER(PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY EventTimestamp ASC)`

Comment: @scsimon thanks for responding to OP, have updated my answer to include your comment.

Comment: No sweat @Tanner